# Spring multipart file max size

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring `MultipartFile` in my Spring MVC controller. I know that there is a property which is responsible for handling max file size of `MultipartFile`, however I was unable to find out what is the maximum possible value for the property, I mean what is a max files size I can download via `MultipartFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however I was unable to find out what is the maximum possible value
>   for the property

Default value for `maxFileSize` of [`MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html#maxFileSize--) is `-1`, which means unlimited.

> I mean what is a max files size I can **download** via MultipartFile?

These abstractions are designed to handle file uploads, they're not for downloading files. Checkout the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart) for more information.

Comment: @christopher I was talking about the servlet's `MultipartConfig` default value, not the Spring Boot's default value provided by ithe `MultipartProperties` which is 1 MB.

Comment: So can a client send a server a 500+mb file?